# Does the entity framework ObjectContext maintain references after iterating over the results

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4

the use case that I'm concerned with in this post involves iterating over a large number of entities (100K+) returned from a query.

Given the following code snippet:

```
var query = from c in context.Customers select c;
foreach(var customer in query)
    printCustomerStatement(customer);
```

In this example it's clear that the the customer instance is not needed after the call to printCustomerStatement.  Will the ObjectContext be keeping a reference to it regardless?  My expectation is that it would not. and that this foreach would behave like a forward-only read-only enumerator method call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depends on the query `MergeOption`.

If you do this:

```
context.Customers.MergeOption = MergeOption.NoTracking;
var query = from c in context.Customers select c;
foreach(var customer in query)
    printCustomerStatement(customer);
```

...then the context won't store those references.

With the default `MergeOption` of `AppendOnly`, it will.